# Android Caldroid selected date format issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio, calendar, caldroid

I want to highlight selected day in Caldroid calendar but when I am selecting the date it will successfully highlighted, but after that when I pick another date then it will highlight both the dates.

**for instance:-**

[image]

**And expected output will be:-**

[image]

**Note:- Pink colour shows selected date and purple colour shows date having events.**

Answer (score 0):

Use this caldroidFragment.clearSelectedDates(); before select any Date